# It's a good practice do this em gemfile rails when you need the same gem twice for different env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I need to do this, because  we have gem on our servers, and I need the homologation version with a branch to develop one more production and require a branch master.
For CI to work properly.

Rails do not allow you to use different branches or paths for the same gem within the gemfile. So I did it that way and it worked, and it's a good practice to do this?, or someone knows another way to solve this problem.

```
branch = 'master'

group :development, :homolog do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  branch = 'develop'
end

gem 'some_gem_engine', '>= 1.5.4', git: 'git@gitlabserverip:engines/some_gem_engine.git', branch: branch
```

Comment: This might be a better option for you: http://bundler.io/v1.15/git.html#local. Have you checked to ensure that your gem actually installs master branch for production environment with your current Gemfile?

Comment: i use this option of bundler to manage a gem in develop env, but in homolog and production its on the server..
Yes, at current config, all it's ok